# Wavelet estimates in Gaussian White Noise Model

Tags: python, statistics, numerical-methods

I try to implement (from scratch) in Python a wavelet estimator in the Gaussian White Noise Model (see equation 1.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03863.pdf) using Haar wavelets (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet). But the result obtained so far are unsatisfying and i think there is something that i do not understand or some silly error in my code. Also if there is package to do things more directly i would be glad to know about it.

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def psi(k,l,t):
  if (l-1)/2**k<=t<l/2**k:
    return(-1)
  if  l/2**k<t<(l+1)/2**k:
    return(1)
  else:
    return(0)

def waveletcoef(k,l,X):
  S=0
  for i in range(len(X)-1):
    S=S+(X[i+1]-X[i])*psi(k,l,i/len(X))
  return(S)

def Wavelet_aprox(K,X,t):
  S=0
  for k in range(K):
    for l in range(2**k):
      S=S+waveletcoef(k,l,X)*psi(k,l,t)
  return(S)

def f(x):
  return(np.cos(x*(4*np.pi)))

m=1000
truefonc=np.zeros(m)
for i in range(m):
  truefonc[i]= f(i/m)

n=1000

x = np.zeros(m)
x[0]=f(0)
for i in range(m - 1):
    x[i + 1] = x[i] + f(i/m)*1/m + (1/(m*n))**(1/2) * np.random.randn()

K=9

approx1=np.zeros(m)
for i in range(m):
  approx1[i]= Wavelet_aprox(K,x,i/m)

plt.plot([i/m for i in range(m)],approx1, 'red')
plt.plot([i/m for i in range(m)],truefonc, 'blue')
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is apparently not a programming problem, but more of a math comprehension problem or to realize a math algorithm as numerical approximation. The place for those are math.SE or scicomp.SE, but in both places with a more detailed mathematical description of what you aim to achieve. It partially looks like an SDE solution.

Comment: Thank you, i was not sure where to post it taking account that it's mostly a computational question but i will post my question on math.SE !

Comment: You should expand on your scenario. So you have an "Ito quadrature", there is no feed-back, just simple integration, and want to reconstruct the trend coefficient using the detail coefficients of the wavelet transform. One weakness that I see is the sampling of the wavelet coefficients. There should be at least a weak effort at numerical integration be visible. In general, the numerical differentiation of noisy functions can look rather random, so one has to carefully discuss when weird becomes too weird and thus indicative of an error.